# My ribs are aching after a pushup. What's wrong?

Tags: exercise, pain, push-ups

This is not the first time i'm doing a push-up but i think this is probably the first time i'm doing it well hence the pain on my right rib. I want to know if this is normal and if it is, should i continue my daily pushup or wait till the pain is gone.

Comment: The pain is in your rib bone?

Comment: How are you doing the push-up? E.g. elbows out or elbows close to the body?

Comment: @FredrikD, I;m not sure cos i don't know the difference but i want to assume that it's "elbows out".

Comment: If you feel something is always medically wrong, always consult a physician. Since your ribs cover such a large span, there is no way to tell what it might be without being more specific. Your: Seratus Anterior, Intercostal, Diaphragm; Pectoral; Latissimus; etc. muscles all have rib involvement. If you are a little more specific, we can try to narrow it down for you; but, (even though it doesn't sound like much of anything) I would still consult your physician.

Comment: +1 on @Grohlier comment. Pain is your bodies way of saying "Something is wrong".

Comment: Generally when we start doing heavy exercise, we used to see some pain in body but in your situation, better you consult physician to get best advice.

Comment: I think we should close this question, it doesn't seem to be a common problem but a rather specific one which might need professional attention.

Answer (score 0):

A very common injury during bench presses or push-ups is a small cartilage or muscle tear in either the internal or external obliques - can also happen to the anterior muscle group, which are higher but usually this is not as painful.  There are a lot of reasons why including not warming up, a previous injury, movement wasn't even (one side going up or down faster than the other), turning the trunk during the chest movement...  There are generally small muscles and muscle/cartilage tears do not take much action.

These will feel like a "broken rib" or a stabbing pain the ribs.  Do you need to see a dr for this sort of injury?  If you want.  Do you have to see a dr?  No.  There is no treatment other than ice and rest.  When I was younger and muscles weren't as developed I had this happen several times.  Usually a few days before the sharp pain goes away.

Comment: You are so confident in saying that the questioner need not see a Doctor; can you explain why and how are you so confident about it? Just asking.

Comment: Because I would put this in the category of a bruised elbow or cut my finger.  Can you see a doctor?  Yes.  Unless you have a broken rib your dr. will not even be able to tell you exactly what is wrong.  I have broken at least 10 ribs (boxed for years) and never did a dr. do anything for me except tell me a rib was broken.  If you think he should see a dr then you must still be on parents medical plan.

Comment: No I'm not accusing you of anything. I just wanted to know your qualification for your suggestion and more support for your answer

Comment: @DMoore just because you have had bad experiences with your doctors that's no reason to make guesses what a medical professional will tell him. And please note that there are more countries in the world which have far better health plans available, questions and answers at fitness.SE should be applicable to the whole world.

Comment: Prepare for down vote city.  The hive mind mentality here is as bad as Reddit.

Comment: @Tip_Top -- true true... I give people real advice.  Going to the dr because you have a boo boo is not feasible for 95% of the world.

Comment: @Informaficker - I have had great experiences with doctors.  I have many doctors as good friends and my life saved by a doctor.  I am still very good friends with my olympic team doctor.  He is the one that told me there is basically nothing they can do for rib issues (other than tell me to stop working out and a little stem).  A person posting in a fitness site about rib discomfort should be told how to prevent this (warming up and building up the area) not run to their dr (who will tell them to stop working out for 3-4 weeks) and then they will have the same injury a few months later.

Comment: @DMoore I agree with that, but currently there is too little information in the question, we don't even know what kind of pain it is, how severe the pain level is etc. As you should always assume the worst case unless told otherwise (which the OP didn't do) I think it is dangerous to assume that it is a common problem, although it chances are high. And always take into account that other people might come here, think they have the same problem as the OP (which they don't) and take your advice.